# Is mongodb database available while it is being sharded?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I am sharding a large-scale database in mongodb. Since the amount of documents in the collection is over 100,000,000, so, it will take a really long time to shard, right? I am now doing the sharding operation for this database, and the command line is just in the waiting state. How can I check if the shard operation is processing normally?

Comment: when you mean "sharding" do you actually mean "balancing" as in distributing the documents across the multiple shards?

Comment: From where are you populating data? Can't you do it after setting up shard db server?

Comment: Good question from Amol.I find mongodb will fall into a long long wait after I set up shard for a database which has already been filled with data. But after I clean the database , set up the shard and refill it will data, mongoDB works well.I can see clearly about the shard status now.Thanks.If it's convenient ,vote for me ,ok?

Comment: For Asya,Yes ,I guess so.But since the data is really large-scale ,I cannot wait anymore to guess if the mongodb is just distributing the data or just have already died.So ,I restart mongodb and clear the database ,set up the shard before it has any data  and then refill the data.In this way , it works.If it's convenient ,vote for me ,ok?

Comment: @AmolMKulkarni Your question is absolutely correct.Yes, I shouldn't have shard before populating data,I have to shard before I populate data.I do so and a long long wait never happened.

Comment: I'm afraid I reserve my votes for questions which are likely to be helpful to many people.  Your question is somewhat unclear/ambiguous and it's not at all clear to me that either the question nor the answer offered is going to be useful to anyone else.  You are sharding a large collection? (you don't partition a DB but a collection) and your problem is that balancing is slow?  You didn't even specify what exact command you ran when the command line hung nor what the full stats of the collection were, nor what shard key you were using ...

Comment: Well，in fact ,it is because I should shard the database before I populated all the data to it.Never should I populate all the data to a database whose shard configuration is ready but haven't be shard-enabled . In than case,I run sh.enableSharding("database name") and sh.shardCollection(),the terminal will fall into a forever wait. But if I run sh.enableSharding("database name") and sh.shardCollection() on a empty database ,and then populate the data to it , data can be sharded into different shard while I am inserting data.

Comment: You are confusing sharding a collection (which is a meta-data change) with balancing chunks across multiple shards (balancing) which is the slow part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well，in fact ,it is because I should shard the database before I populated all the data to it.Never should I populate all the data to a database whose shard configuration is ready but haven't be shard-enabled . In that case,I run sh.enableSharding("database name") and sh.shardCollection(),the terminal will fall into a forever wait. But if I run sh.enableSharding("database name") and sh.shardCollection() on a empty database ,and then populate the data to it , data can be sharded into different shard while I am inserting data.
Well ,another piece of  experience.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following steps (*order matter*):

1. Set up shard MongoDB server
2. Then, do the sharding operation for the database you got (collection
   with documents over 100,000,000 or so..)